# Future<Boolean> is null?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, future

following is my problem:
I wrote a method for caching some sql-query results and a implementation for the hasnext() Method from Iterator.

```
public Future<Boolean> cache(){
    return CSCore.dbManager.sqlprocessor.submit(() -> {
        checker.writeLock().lock();
        iterate.lock();
        data = HashBasedTable.create();
        try {
            while (result.next()) {
                for (int i = 1; i <= result.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) {
                    data.put(result.getInt(1), result.getMetaData().getColumnName(i), result.getObject(i));
                }
            }
            checker.writeLock().unlock();
            iterate.unlock();
            return true;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            DatabaseManager.handlesqlexception(e);
            CSCore.instance.getLogger().info(CSCore.infoDsp.get(data_fetch));
            checker.writeLock().unlock();
            iterate.unlock();
            return false;
        }
    });
    }

@Override
public boolean hasNext() {
    if(this.data == null){
        CSCore.instance.getLogger().info(CSCore.infoDsp.get(forced_caching));
        try {
            cache().get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            CSCore.instance.getLogger().info(CSCore.infoDsp.get(row_get));
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
    return current != this.data.rowKeySet().size() - 1;
}
```

so when hasNext() is called, im getting a nullpointerexception when calling chache().get()
Following is the the StackTrace:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
[18:44:01 WARN]:        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
[18:44:01 WARN]:        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
[18:44:01 WARN]:        at de.zortax.comsrv.core.data.RowSet.hasNext(RowSet.java:214)
[18:44:01 WARN]:        at de.zortax.comsrv.core.user.UserProfile.lambda$loadFromDatabase$0(UserProfile.java:34)
[18:44:01 WARN]:        at de.zortax.comsrv.core.concurrent.ThreadExecutor$2.runTask(ThreadExecutor.java:32)
[18:44:01 WARN]:        at de.zortax.comsrv.core.concurrent.CSTask.run(CSTask.java:21)
[18:44:01 WARN]:        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_9_R1.scheduler.CraftTask.run(CraftTask.java:71)
[18:44:01 WARN]:        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_9_R1.scheduler.CraftScheduler.mainThreadHeartbeat(CraftScheduler.java:350)
[18:44:01 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.v1_9_R1.MinecraftServer.D(MinecraftServer.java:729)
[18:44:01 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.v1_9_R1.DedicatedServer.D(DedicatedServer.java:400)
[18:44:01 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.v1_9_R1.MinecraftServer.C(MinecraftServer.java:660)
[18:44:01 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.v1_9_R1.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:559)
[18:44:01 WARN]:        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[18:44:01 WARN]: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
[18:44:01 WARN]:        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:213)
[18:44:01 WARN]:        at com.google.common.collect.StandardTable.put(StandardTable.java:140)
[18:44:01 WARN]:        at com.google.common.collect.HashBasedTable.put(HashBasedTable.java:55)
[18:44:01 WARN]:        at de.zortax.comsrv.core.data.RowSet.lambda$cache$3(RowSet.java:138)
[18:44:01 WARN]:        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[18:44:01 WARN]:        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
[18:44:01 WARN]:        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
[18:44:01 WARN]:        ... 1 more
```

neither the dbmanagerm nor the sqlprocessor is null, they should be initiated before those methods are called.
What am i making wrong? I mean, if it's not like the Future-Object returns null, the whole Method cache() is returning null or at least throwing a null pointer.

Comment: Rather than rolling your own caching, you might want to check out caffeine: https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine

Comment: thank you for the tip, but in this case, we just need something pretty small and easy to use. Also, we wont cache big amounts of data, so there is not a need for that :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem is in the `hasNext()`. If `if(this.data == null)` is true, there will be a NullPointer, if no exception occours. I think you may miss a return statement before `cache().get()`.

Comment: but cache is initiating the "data" field. it just checks if data has already been cached, and if not, it caches the data.

Answer (score 0):

OK, found the error. Guava Table does not accepts null as a value and is throwing a nullpointer exception. Simply fixed it with a simple if clause, putting a new Object() into the map, when the retrieved object is null.